# how to append text and bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i am trying to combine bootstrap datepicker along with some text.Say for example

```
hello 12/12/2013
```

In the jsfiddle Suppose if i write hello and then choose a date then the word hello is replaced by the date.
this is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/) showing bootstrap datepicker,Please tell me how to append some text along with datepicker.Following is the jquery code to get the datepicker.i am referring this site for bootstrap [datepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

```
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'pt-BR'
      });
```

Comment: Can you add documentation of your datepicker? the link.

Comment: @DonovanCharpin Please see the link in my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this..

```
var val=" ";
   $(function() {
     $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "yyyy-MM-dd",
        linkField: "#txt",
        linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true,
    });

 jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){



 var chk=$(".darea1").val();
 chk=chk.replace(val, " ");;
 $(".darea1").val(chk);

     $(".darea1").val($( ".darea1" ).val()+$( "#txt" ).val());
    val=$( "#txt" ).val();



});

});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/4/)

Comment: I have some queries and sent you a mail

Answer (score 2):

Simply, if you want the same text for any date chosen:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hello dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        language: 'pt-BR'
      });
```

And, if like in your example, you dont want the time:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'hello dd/MM/yyyy',
        language: 'pt-BR'
      });
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GP9c/3/).

Comment: See in the jsfiddle when you click the button it only displays date and time.I want some text along with date time.Example **hello 12/12/2013 12:20**

Comment: In your code the word hello is fixed.i dont want like this.I mean to say that user will write hello then click on the button choose a date.So finally it will be hello 12/12/2013 12:20

Comment: This is not what you asked for, you said you need to combine bootstrap datepicker along with some text. You mentioned nothing about the text being an input from the user.

Comment: I should have mentioned no predefined word

Comment: Its my mistake but +1 for your useful answer